# Running UI test in Azure Devops and viewing the test (RDP) as different user

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, automated-tests

I'm trying to run Selenium tests on Azure devops.
I'm using self hosted agent. I've run the agent interactively. the agent is configured to run as USER1

Now when I run the pipeline the tests are running fine. When I try to view the running tests by rdp into the machine I am able to view them as well.

However when user2 runs the pipeline, the user is unable to see the running tests, but user1 is able to see the tests.

How can we configure the agent so that, any user (user1, user2, user3) that runs the pipeline should also be able to view the running tests when they rdp into that agent which is running the test

Answer (score 1):

When your UI tests run, applications and browsers are launched in the context of the user specified in the auto-logon settings. So other users can not see the running test.

If you use Remote Desktop to access the computer on which an agent is running with auto-logon, simply disconnecting the Remote Desktop causes the computer to be locked and any UI tests that run on this agent may fail.

Check here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-testing-using-self-hosted-windows-agents

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?